# Record changes in Document Library. File Updated, File Replaced File's Metadata updated etc

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api, events

I'm using SharePoint REST API. I want to know if we can monitor changes in Document Library(Shared Documents).
I want to know if we can list the events below.

1. File's Content is Updated
2. File's Metadata is Updated (Title or any column)
3. File has been replaced
4. File has been Deleted/Trashed
5. Folder has been Deleted/Trashed

If any of the above is possible, please provide the relevant URL to make API calls.

Comment: I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.

Comment: I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most of this is covered by SharePoint [version history](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-the-version-history-of-an-item-or-file-in-a-list-or-library-53262060-5092-424d-a50b-c798b0ec32b1) and the Microsoft Graph API has endpoints for fetching these versions:

[List versions of a driveItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-versions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[Listing versions of a ListItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/listitem_list_versions?view=odsp-graph-online)

Alternatively, you can use the following endpoint:

```
/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items(1)/versions
```